# InspectorPackage did not load correctly

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I recently installed Xamarin.  I experienced no issues with it for about a week.  Now, when i load visual studio I get an alert that says:

> The 'InspectorPackage' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension.  You can get more information by examining the file
>   'C:\Users{redacted}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
>
> Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.
>
> Continue to show this error message?

Restarting Visual Studio does not resolve this issue.

Upon inspecting the xml file, I find:

```
<entry>
    <record>503</record>
    <time>2017/02/15 15:33:56.686</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [InspectorPackage]Source: 
        &apos;&apos; Description: Not implemented 
        (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))&#x000D;&#x000A;
        System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented 
        (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))&#x000D;&#x000A;   
        at EnvDTE.Project.get_FullName()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
        at Xamarin.Inspector.VS.VSAgentExecutionTarget..ctor(Project proj)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
        at Xamarin.Inspector.VS.VSInspectorSession.CreateAgentExecutionTarget()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
        at Xamarin.Interactive.IdeSupport.InspectorSession.Prepare()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
        at Xamarin.Inspector.VS.InspectorPackage.RefreshInspectorSession()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
        at Xamarin.Inspector.VS.InspectorPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)
    </description>
    <guid>{0FCBA9C6-0554-418C-8B79-FF2ED7DC658D}</guid>
    <hr>80004001 - E_NOTIMPL</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
</entry>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error seems to only appear when you have multiple startup projects in a solution.

I reproduced it by creating an empty solution with two empty console projects.  When only one is set as startup everything works fine.  However, when setting both as startup this error pops up.

I also came across this bug where the last post on 14 Jan 2017 states that the upcoming version 1.1 release will fix this issue: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=49417

You can check your version in the about box in VS.  On VS2015 it is **Help | About Microsoft Visual Studio** and I reckon it is the **Xamarin Inspector Support** entry.  Mine is at 1.0.0.0 so I assume I'll have to wait for the upcoming release :)

***update***:

Oddly enough, an update just arrived for the Xamarin Inspector (less than 30 min after answering).  The first load of my test solution still popped up with the error but after that it seems fine.

***update (28 Feb 2017)***:

I am still experiencing the issue with the following version:

`Xamarin Inspector Support   1.1.2.0 (cdc01b9f4466b6dcc3095828824a12d041c9f55e)
Adds support for inspecting Xamarin and WPF apps.`

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did and it worked for me:

1)  go to the path of Visual Studio and delete everything in that folder 
(this will delete you visual studio set up ) Visual Studio wont work after this
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio`

2) uninstall Visual Studio. And install it again.

If this didn't work look around for xamarin files in that folder and delete everything inside.